# Adding a value at the end of an iframe's src

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

in my website I use flipbooks made with Flip PDF Professional (here's an example: https://istitutometacultura.org/progetto_babar/storie_di_babar/il_ritorno_a_casa_di_babar/microstoria.html), and I embed them into the pages using iframes (example of parent page with embedded flipbook: https://edumediateca.istitutometacultura.org/il-ritorno-a-casa-di-babar2/). These flipbooks also have the function of opening directly to a specific page, if you add "#p=X" to the end (X is the page number). Now, sometimes I need to link a specific page of the flipbook, so the flipbook link will be, for example, "https://istitutometacultura.org/progetto_babar/storie_di_babar/il_ritorno_a_casa_di_babar/microstoria.html#p=5", but this will take me to the html page, and I want the user to be taken to the page with the iframe (https://edumediateca.istitutometacultura.org/il-ritorno-a-casa-di-babar2/), not to the html file.
Since I don't want to duplicate the page just to add "#p=5" to the iframe's src, is there a way to add a value to the end of the src maybe putting it into the parent page url? (for example, if the url is https://edumediateca.istitutometacultura.org/il-ritorno-a-casa-di-babar2#p=5 the iframe's src will change from "......html" to "......html#p=5"). I don't know what to do, I really need this mechanism to work in order to publish my services... Something in Javascript or C#?

Comment: After the page is loaded, grab `location.hash` (it'll be `#p=5`) and append it to the iframe's `.src`

Comment: Please show us some of your code.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks a lot for your suggestion, I'll try to do it.